# Display django Model fields in a table

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I have Model with 30+ fields and I want to display about 20 of them in a table. I know that there is `{{ form.as_table }}` but is there a comparable function for non-form models? I am currently using

> ```
> {% for name, value in article.get_fields %}
>      <tr>
>      {% if value %}
>         <td>{{ name }} = {{ value }}</td> 
>      {% endif %}
>      </tr>
> {% endfor %}
> ```

-where get_fields returns all the fields of Article. This works fine. I would guess that there is a built-in django function for doing the same thing, but I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: There is no such already available utility like this. However, you can write your own html files and render via a templatetag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @kathikr, there isn't a function built in to the model class to do this for you.

One option would be to subclass Model and add a as_table() function to it that parsed available fields and used an exclude attribute where necessary.

```
    def as_table(self):
            return "".join(["<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>" % (field.verbose_name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in self._meta.fields if field not in self.exclude])
```

hmm, this probable shouldn't be a one-liner

```
    def as_table(self):
        result = ""
        for field in self._meta.fields:
            if field not in self.exclude:
                result += "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>" % 
                    (field.verbose_name, field.value_to_string(self))
        return result
```